# What could be a good scalable alternative to polling data and then looping over a list of objects for triggering some action on those?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, scalability, stream-processing, polling

So I have some naive implementation for the following problem:

1. We have a list of objects with action methods that have to be trigger at some value of interest.
2. This value is polled (or is streamed) from a remote server and is constantly changing.
3. Let's say we have tens of thousands of such objects in the list, and the remote value changes every couple of tens of milliseconds.

What could be a good scalable alternative to such code in order to handle the requirements?

Pseudo-code code looks as follows:

```js
while true:{
   //get some data from continosly changing source
   responseData = getRequest('http://some-remote-endpoint')
   //check our all objects of interest
   for object in list {
       /* if the object has to be triggered at a 
       specific remote source value, trigger an action on it. */
       if object.triggerAtValue == reponseData.value {
            object.triggerAction()
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the remote service yours or a third party? Can you change it? Why are you using polling to begin with?

Comment: @JohnWu no it cannot be changed, it's 3rd party, or could be multiple ones if we talk scale. Some of them provide sockets, some just REST endpoints.

Comment: Will one responsedata only ever trigger one object or can one responsedata trigger multiple?

Comment: @PieterB it can be multiple and there are no foreseeable limits really, it can be thousands and more objects have to get triggered by a single value(event for that matter).

Comment: Since you can't change the polling endpoint, you can at least insulate yourself from it.  Consider having your "poller" feed into one or more broadcast message queues and having your interested objects subscribe to them.

Comment: OP, if you are stuck using polling, then yes, the only way to know if anything changed is to compare it to its old value. Don't think you can escape that. That being said, there may be more efficient ways to perform the comparison, but that would depend on the specifics of the message format, O/S, and programming language. There is no "better" architecture in general.

Comment: @ChuckAdams thanks for your comment. does the pub sub pattern really solve the problem? is it not under the hood still simply going to loop over the subscribed objects to find out what handlers to trigger?

Comment: Yes it's effectively a loop, but a broadcast at least parallelizes to as many listeners as you have.  Your architecture itself might need some rethinking, it's impossible to say how right now, and this is already turning into an extended discussion thread as it is.